# Bootstrap use select as input add-on

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to replace the `input-group-addon` with a `select` input but it's giving me positioning issues. I'm able to click the dropdown and select the options but the width is all wrong. I'll post an image below of what it looks like.

I want the select to be right next to the input because the user will be able to input a size in either mm or in.

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="wrapped">Wrapped Around</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="wrapped" placeholder="Wrapped Around" name="wrapped" step="0.01">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <select class="form-control">
                <option selected>Pick</option>
                <option>mm</option>
                <option>in</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
#wrapped+.input-group-addon {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-width: 8rem;
    border: none;
}
#wrapped+.input-group-addon>.form-control {
    border-radius: 0 .4rem .4rem 0;
    border-left: none;
}

/* CSS below is for centering the div in the page, you only need what is above this line */

body {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
body {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
}
body > .form-group {
    width: 50vw;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
      integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" 
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      />
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="wrapped">Wrapped Around</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input id="wrapped" 
           class="form-control" 
           type="number" 
           placeholder="Wrapped Around" 
           name="wrapped" 
           step="0.01"
           />
    <div class="input-group-addon">
      <select class="form-control">
        <option selected>Pick</option>
        <option>mm</option>
        <option>in</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Screen capture, as per comments:

[image]

Does anyone experience the problem Joe mentions in comments: `border-radius` not being reset on the left side of the select?

Comment: Is there a way to remove the border-radius from the left side? I'm unable to do it.

Comment: Yes. `border-radius:0 .4rem .4rem 0;` You only have to use a stronger selector than the existing one. As you can see, it works in my code. Provide a complete example and I'll give you the proper selector.

Comment: I added a screen capture with what I get in Chrome. What are you getting? And in what browser? [IE8? Opera Mini?](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius)

Comment: In chrome I get what you have there except the left side of the select has a border radius.

Comment: This is strange, to say the least. Same browser, same code, different result. Can you post a screen-shot with what you're getting? Does anyone else get `border-radius` on the left side of the `select` in Chrome? Can you provide further details? OS, browser version, device?

Comment: That was weird why my account got suspended. Anyway I ended up using two different input groups and styled them accordingly. Thank you for your help.